# Changing between Python 2.x and 3.x in windows CMD?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I have both Python 2.7 and 3.4 installed on my Windows Machine. When I type Python in CMD it defaults to Python2.7.  How do I switch to 3.4?

Comment: Have you tried `python3`?

Comment: Have you tried to change the path? I personally prefer to have a shortcut with the every...something like python2.7.cmd and python3.4.cmd

Comment: python3 is not recognized.

Comment: Use the [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher).

Answer (score 4):

Create two batch files, `python2.bat` and `python3.bat`. Have each batch file add the appropriate Python directory to the path, then launch `python.exe`.

E.G. Python2.bat:

```
@echo off
set OLDPATH=%PATH%
path C:\Python27;%PATH%
python.exe
path %OLDPATH%
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to make changes to the PATH environmental variable. To do this, click the Start button, right click on "Computer", hit "Properties", click "Advanced System Settings" in the left sidebar. Then click the Environmental Variables button.

Under User or System variables, there will be a variable called "PATH" that includes a path to you Python installation. You can change this to the Python 3 install path.

You can also change the name of the Python 3 executable to "python3.exe", and add the directory to the path variable, separating it from other directories with a semicolon. Then you can use both 2 and 3 by calling `python` and `python3` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Simply changing the name of the python.exe to anything (ex:pytoioion.exe) in your C:/Python34 or C:/Python27 will switch between the two versions. To verify, run this on your command prompt

C:Users/(your_name)>python